# Recyclerview jerking when scrolling

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, scroll, android-recyclerview, cardview

I have a recyclerview. Each item is a cardview with an imageview and textviews. On scrolling, at the beginning of each item recyclerview jerks/jumps and then proceeds with smooth scroll. I researched alot and found no solution. Someone please help. I am using data binding with MVVM architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I added the code `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);` which was the reaso for the jerking. Removing this line made recyclerview scrolling perfect.

Comment: use of `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);` is not recommended. Using it ruins the whole point of recyclerView.